# JQuery, toggling a class on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a class to a  within a block of generated content coming from JSON. I believe it's barking on the toggleClass because the HTML is actually not generated yet. I figure I probably need to use .on() or .live() in some fashion.

I am not receiving an error, it's just not adding the class. Again, because the table content is being built dynamically I believe.

Here's the relevant code.

```
// The data variable is a block of JSON
for(i=1; i < data.length; i++){
 foo += '<tr id="'+data[i][2]+'">test</tr>';

 // Here's where I am trying to add the class, but it is not working. We check to see if a value in our JSON is true, if so - we change the class.
if(data[i][1]){
 $("#"+data[i][2]).toggleClass("newClass"); // finds the ID by unique name
}

}
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ IDs must be unique.

Comment: They are, I just left out some stuff I believe was not needed. I'll update my example.

Comment: @jason - that sounds like some pretty important stuff... You posted code that wouldn't work in the first place... Please post the code that you are using - don't change it - just remove irrelevant parts...

Comment: Updated, thanks. I'm building the ID from column 2 in our JSON as you can see, and I am checking if column 1 in our JSON for that row is true or not.

Comment: anyone looking at this post will immediately point to duplicate id's... you should change it...

Comment: Updated to show how the selector is actually working to select the unique ID.

Comment: "I figure I probably need to use .on() or .live() in some fashion." -- yep, probably. So what's your question?

Comment: Because I am not sure what event to pass to on or live :) It's not a click, a mouse over, or anything. I just need it to toggle the class if the column in JSON is true.

Comment: I'm not sure why Raminson's comment is getting upvoted, my ID's are unique?

Comment: will `$("#"+data[i][2])` select an element that is in the DOM, or is it something in the JSON object?  And all of your `tr` elements in your code above will have an id of "bar", thus non-unique IDs

Comment: Ack, my mistake - I left that bar in there from my original example, it's updated now. Sorry about that. And yes, that will select the TR in my example (now that I updated).

Comment: I'm not sure do you really use this or not and is this related to your question or not but id here is not unique `foo += '<tr id="bar">test</tr>';` and what is the `data`?

Comment: Hi Haynar, that was as mistake - I updated the code, please refresh.

Comment: yes, sorry. but however... what is the content of data?

Comment: a JSON result set. [i][1] will either return true or false

Comment: are you sure that element with that ID is really there?

Comment: It's dynamic, but yes it is there.

Comment: I mean what's the result if you use `console.log($("#"+data[i][2]))` ?

Comment: It's empty, but my ID on my table rows have data and I am using the exact same value. Again, I think this is because I am building these rows dynamically and then appending them to a DIV. I am trying to evaluate the row and toggle a class before it is appended.

Comment: Are you talking about those `tr` inside for loop which are not been inserted in the dom ?

Comment: Sheikh, correct :) - I need to toggle a class on those if my JSON result has a true in one of the columns. I know they haven't been appended to the DOM yet, and I know I probably need on() or live(), but not sure on the syntax in this case. Normally I need an event to use those.

Comment: The other way to do this would be to just do it in an IF statement and build the row differently if the value is true. I was hoping to avoid that and just append a class to the row though.

Comment: if you're building table using DOM methods you have to create `tbody` element inside `table`, and place your `tr` elements inside `tbody`

Comment: haynar, not sure how adding a tbody would help solve this problem? BTW, I have tbody elements.

Comment: Without appending those `tr` in to `dom` table you can't toggle the class in this way, you have to append first, because `$("#"+data[i][2])` will look for the element in the `dom`.

Comment: Sheikh, so there is no trick with using .on() or .live()

Comment: After you append them in to the `dom`.

Comment: Do you need to add a class in to `<tr id="'+data[i][2]+'">test</tr>` before append to the dom ?

Comment: Sheikh, yes, but I went ahead and just did an if statement :) Thanks for helping me think through it.

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass only works on DOM objects, at the point you're calling it the element does not exist as a DOM object, only as part of you string.

you can either wait with the toggle class until after you added the elements to the DOM, add the classes into the string, or (my preference) turn them into elements before you inject them into the DOM.
something like:

```
$(foo).toggleClass("newClass").appendTo("#whatever")'
```